# How to fix merge replacing files

Tags: git, github, git-svn

I want to pull in server (hostgator share) from bitbucket repository. But I got, few of my unnecessary files has been changed in the server which makes merge conflict. So, I want, those files would be replaced avoiding merge or not to be updated once I pull. Is it possible, if so how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

use `git stash` to save the files, do the merge then apply them back with `git stash apply`

Assuming you only want to save a subset of the changes in your workspace, you can use `git stash --keep-index`, which will keep only those files you have staged with `git add`

If it is just a one off, and you want to keep your version of *all* conflicting files, then you could add the `-s ours` parameter to the merge call (if you only want your version of conflicting hunks, then use `-s recursive -Xours` If it is always the same file(s) then you can use a `.gitattributes` file to specify the per file merge strategy.

Comment: is it possible to avoid merge rather replacing those files or not to be updated?